# Trying to understand some claims on chromatic number of union of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G_1=(V,E_1)$ and $G_2=(V,E_2)$ be graphs. Let $c_1:V\to[\chi(G_1)]$ and $c_2:V\to[\chi(G_2)]$ be proper colourings of $G_1$ and $G_2$ respectively.

My questions:

1. I am trying to understand the claim that $c:V\to[\chi(G_1)]\times[\chi(G_2)]$ given by $c(v):=(c_1(v),c_2(v))$ is a proper colouring of $G(V,E_1\cup E_2)$. Let us represent the colours by integers then say $c(v')=(7,23)$, what does it exactly mean? Does it mean the vertex $v'$ has to different colours $7$ and $23$ under two different mappings $c_1$ and $c_2$? So what is the actual colour of $v'$ in $G$?
2. I am also trying to understand how can it imply $\chi(G)\leq\chi(G_1)\chi(G_2)$? I understand roughly that $\chi(G)=\chi(G_1)\chi(G_2)$ is possible when $E_1$ or $E_2$ is an empty set. But I struggle to show from the previous claim of $c:V\to[\chi(G_1)]\times[\chi(G_2)]$ to $\chi(G)\leq\chi(G_1)\chi(G_2)$. What particularly concerns me is why do we have the $"\leq"$? Could somebody please give some help?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. The colour of $v'$ in $G$ $\textit{is}$ the pair $(7, 23)$. 2. The previous claim means that if $G_1$ is colourable (via $c_1$) with $\chi(G_1)$-many colours, and similarly for $G_2$, then $c$ is a colouring of $G_1 \times G_2$ with $\chi(G_1) \times \chi(G_2)$-many colours.

Comment: @qaphla Thanks. For question 2, I think you meant $G_1\cup G_2$ instead of $G_1\times G_2$?. And what concerns me is why we have the $"\leq"$?

Comment: Yes, I did mean $G_1 \cup G_2$. We have the $\le$ because we can certainly colour $G_1 \cup G_2$ with $\chi(G_1) \times \chi(G_2)$ many colours, but there's no reason that we need all of the colours --- for example, if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are vertex-disjoint bipartite graphs, then $\chi(G_1 \cup G_2) = 2 = \chi(G_1) = \chi(G_2)$.